# print from the middle of the text area in java

Tags: java, textarea

Date of Admission to the Institute : 09.07.2012

Date on which he left the Institute : April,2016

Class in which he was studying at
 the time of leaving               : Completed- B.Tech in Information Technology

This is how the output needs to be displayed, but if the text in the last line is increased, it gets printed from the beginning of the line. Instead, it needs to be displayed on the next line and from the middle of the page. Given this, how should I align text area?

The following code works if text in the last line has got only two lines:

```
 int indexOfIn = integrated.indexOf(" in ");

  if("B.Tech Information Technology".equals(dept))
   {
    lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis =   integrated.lastIndexOf("Technology");
    upToColon = integrated.substring(0, indexOfIn);
    firstListItem = integrated.substring(indexOfIn + 4,                 
                                            lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis);
    secondListItem = integrated.substring(lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis);
 }

else{

     lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis = integrated.lastIndexOf("Engineering");
     upToColon = integrated.substring(0, indexOfIn);
     firstListItem = integrated.substring(indexOfIn + 4, 
                              lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis);

    secondListItem = integrated.substring(lastIndexOfOpenParenthesis);

     }        
  resultingStr = upToColon +" in"+"\n\n\t\t\t"+" "+firstListItem +    
                                          secondListItem;
```

The last line of the code works only if the text contains only two lines, but it should work with any number of lines. Does anything exist like wordwrap or something like that which does this automatically?

Comment: You can't do what you want with the default Document model for a JTextArea. You will have to either write your own model (ugh!) or else re-think how you display the information. A better way might be a JPanel that contains three JPanel children, with each child containing a JLabel to show the left part and a JTextArea to show the right part. Setting the JTextArea to allow linewrap will then accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I will work in that direction